# Switching Between Screens In android

Tags: android, image, listview, audio, android-intent

My requirement:

```
First screen : list view with images
```

If we click any one of the list,

```
Second Screen: should display a text with image has to play an audio.
```

Where I am lagging is, adding list view with different images using xml not by hard coding it.
                       passing intent and receiving intent(means switching between the screens)

Suggest.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question..Do you want to know how to implement different images images in different row of list view

Comment: K-ran, Yes, I want different images in different row, and these list view text and images not to be hard coded and it should be in xml file.

Answer (score 2):

If you want that data should be dynamic but not hard coded..then you should use  custom adapters.A custom adapters are created by extending the base Adapter class...
For further clarifications check the following link..\
Code is also attached:

```
http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1343
```

or

```
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html
```

Comment: K-ran links provided by you will taught me to use check box, and two images for alternate list items.Is there a way to add all unique images for list of rows?

Answer (score 0):

Yes arvind as you are now aware of Custom adapters..Now you can use a array list which contains all the images in it and array list with names of all imagse which you want to display in listview...
and now pass this arraylist to this adapter at run time..and in the getview() of adapter set images and text to the textView and Imageview according to the position